# How do scale_pos_weight and sample_weight interact in XGBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, unbalanced-classes, hyperparameter, sample-weighting

**Question:**
How do [scale_pos_weight](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html#:%7E:text=of%20hist%20algorithm.-,scale_pos_weight,-%5Bdefault%3D1%5D) and [sample_weight](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier.fit) interact in XGBoost when used at the same time during training? Are they multiplied, added or something else?

**Example when added:**
[image: table showing effects of adding scale_pos_weight and sample_weight]

**Example when multiplied:**
[image: table showing effects of multypling scale_pos_weight and sample_weight]

Answer (score 1):

**scale_pos_weight** illustrates the weight of the positive class relative to the negative class. It is often used when there are **unbalanced classes** - setting the scale_pos_weight to a higher value will penalise errors on the minor class more greatly - helping to ensure that we do not have an unusually high accuracy due to the model being trained primarily on the major class.

On the other hand, **sample_weight** represents the weight specified to each training sample. For instance, if one wishes to append a larger weight to a single data point (e.g. fraudulent transactions of a high value as specified in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079973/xgboost-sample-weights-vs-scale-pos-weight#:%7E:text=The%20sample_weight%20parameter%20allows%20you,approaches%20to%20cost%2Dsensitive%20learning.)).

Using sample_weight changes the importance of a specific value and is assigned a greater weight in its own right. It is not directly interacting with that of the scale_pos_weight per se.

As a hypothetical example, let us say that we have a value of 1, and using scale_pos_weight increases the value by 30%, while sample_weight increases the value by 50%:

**(1 * 1.3) + (1 * 1.5) = 2.8**

In this regard, the two weights are effectively being added as in your example. From a practical standpoint, you should consider whether you are using sample_weight in the right manner. Simply applying it indiscriminately when you are already weighting the minor class with scale_pos_weight defeats the purpose if there is not a sound theoretical reason for assigning higher weights to individual values.

You may also find this reference useful: [Difference between sample_weight and class_weight RandomForest Classifier](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244630/difference-between-sample-weight-and-class-weight-randomforest-classifier)

Comment: 1. How do you know these parameters interact in this specific way?
2. I don't get what's the difference in the nature of these two parameters. It boils down to weighing data points in training, doesn't it? Weighing some "class" more vs weighing some samples more is really the same stuff, right?
3. Besides using scale_pos_weight by default, I was planning to use sample_weight to weigh samples based on their age and the season of the year in which they were gathered. I think it is theoretically justified.

Comment: I would have expected that both weights are used to weight the individual loss in a multiplicative way. I need to check the code though.

Comment: On one hand, I expected scale_pos_weight and sample_weight to be added for easier management and straightforward calculation of final_weights. This is because multiplying these values can result in disproportionate weights with higher magnitudes, as demonstrated in the example I've provided. However, if the weights were added, all samples would have a default final_weight of 2, which is somewhat unnatural.

Comment: "Weighing some "class" more vs weighing some samples more is really the same stuff, right?" Well, no - as the sample may be weighed individually. In the example reference I provided, the author uses the example of weighting an individual fraudulent transaction more heavily due to a higher value of that individual transaction - but did not extend this to all fraudulent transactions. As each sample can differ in their importance, it is not accurate to say that weighting a class versus a sample is the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand the distinction. I see it this way: scale_pos_weight multiplies errors made on positive class samples during training. Sample_weight could do the same exact thing. It is just more flexible. So with this parameter, I can make arbitrary rules/conditions regarding weighing errors. I can put higher weights on a whole class, on just one sample or whatever subset of samples I want. All these parameters do is weigh errors during training, but scale_pos_weight is limited to one condition, whereas sample_weights is not.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that @Mayou36 has an opinion that these two parameters are multiplied with each other, not added to one another (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244630/difference-between-sample-weight-and-class-weight-randomforest-classifier#comment745243_244630). Note however that Mayou's comment is about Random Forest scikit-learn implementation. Sorry, but I will un-accept your answer for now and I will ultimately seek to dive into the xgboost code to see how exactly this stuff is implemented just to make sure.